# How to set this full text index

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I would like some guidance in how to set the full text index in phpMyAdmin like following:

Tables

```
universities:
id
name

programs:
id
name
university_id

courses:
id
name
program_id

students:
id
name
course_id
```

Search function
User needs only to serach for students but I would like to create a full text of the students.name and the courses.name that match the students.course_id and so on so that the students name, course name (student participate in), program name (course is given in) and university name (program belongs to) is all searchable.

Query
If I construct it as above will the full text be created so that it is searchable like standard, e.g. with PDO:

```
$STH = $DBH->prepare('SELECT * FROM students WHERE MATCH(fulltext) AGAINST(:query IN BOOLEAN MODE));
$STH->bindParam(':query', $query);
```

or how would the pdo query in look in php?

Also will this be a heavy search function?

Approx numbers: 5 universities, 100 programs 1 000 courses and 20 000 students.

Answer (score 1):

That's not how `FULLTEXT` indexes work. A `FULLTEXT` index must be on a single textual (`CHAR` / `VARCHAR` / `TEXT`) column in a MyISAM table, and allow searches to match words within the contents of that column. For instance, you might use a FULLTEXT index in a course catalog to allow users to search for text within the course descriptions.

In your case, what you probably want to do is to create one "normal" (non-fulltext) index on each of `students.name`, `courses.name`, `programs.name`, and `universities.name`, then perform one query for each of those tables and merge the results yourself. (You will probably have to display results for a matched student differently than a matched university, for instance.) It may help somewhat to break the existing `student.name` field up into a separate first-name and last-name field, as that'll allow you to search those two separately.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP

```
 $query= "SELECT * FROM students,courses,programes,universities WHERE MATCH(students.name,courses.name,programs.name,universities.name) AGAINST('$keyword' IN BOOLEAN MODE)"
 $result = mysql_query($query);
```

`$keyword` is the word you want to search for.

**EDIT**

Based on the comment, Think this is what you need

```
 SELECT name from student where name like %key% OR 
    course_id IN (SELECT id FROM course WHERE name like %key%) OR 
    course_id IN (SELECT id FROM course WHERE program_id IN (
           SELECT id FROM program WHERE name Like %key%)) OR
    course_id IN (SELECT id FROM course WHERE program_id IN (
      SELECT id FROM program WHERE university_id in (
         SELECT id from university where name like %$key%)))
```

Where `key` is the word you are searching for.

Comment: Since I only want the students returned (matching students if student name is searched or all students in a certain university if university name is searched) can I replace `*` with students.name to achieve that?

Comment: No, for this, I think you need to go for separate queries for the student, courses,programes and universities table.

Comment: Like is this what you want: if the pattern is in student table, you need the student name, if it is in courses tables, then all students in that course, if it is in program , then all students in the course, which are in that program and if it is in university, then all students in the courses, in the programs offered by the university.

Comment: What I need is rather that every student post has the following searchable: student name, course, program, university. But sinced I want it dynamic I do not want to write the course,program and university namestrings in the student table but instead use id to link the tables. And thus the simple full text indexing does not work, but can the full text index be created with help of the linking ids so that every student post gets the correct index. And of course to keep the dynamics: be updated if e.g. the program name is updated?